# Problems with amphp with more than 1k concurrent tcp requests

Tags: amphp

I have created an application using the https://amphp.org framework. It is running with the help of a cronjob (every 5 minutes) sending a concurrent request to some sensors (temperatures) and it saves all the responses.

Up to ~1K sensors everything is working fine.

When increased to 1.5k for about 30% of the requests I am getting the following message:

> Connecting to tcp://*.*.*.*:502 failed: timeout exceeded (10000 ms)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually a limit of up to 1024 file descriptors with `stream_select`, so you'll need one of the extensions, see https://github.com/amphp/amp#requirements.

Comment: Installing 'ev' and 'event' extension (I was not sure which one was better) fixed my problem. Thank you @kelunik for your support. By the way do you know what are the limitations of these php extensions for concurrent socket connection?

Comment: @leoshtika: I'm not aware of any limits when using these extensions. I think which one doesn't matter most of the time.